# Devstack installation error sudo systemctl start devstack@sl-api.service

Tags: openstack, devstack

These are the devstack logs appears on the screen

```
++functions-common:write_uwsgi_user_unit_file:1480  iniset -sudo /etc/systemd/system/devstack@sl-api.service Install WantedBy multi-user.target
    ++functions-common:write_uwsgi_user_unit_file:1483  sudo systemctl daemon-reload
    ++functions-common:_run_under_systemd:1530  sudo systemctl enable devstack@sl-api.service
    Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/devstack@sl-api.service → /etc/systemd/system/devstack@sl-api.service.enter code here
    ++functions-common:_run_under_systemd:1531  sudo systemctl start devstack@sl-api.service
    Job for devstack@sl-api.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
    See "systemctl status devstack@sl-api.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
    +functions-common:_run_under_systemd:1     exit_trap
    +./stack.sh:exit_trap:489                  local r=1
    ++./stack.sh:exit_trap:490                  jobs -p
    +./stack.sh:exit_trap:490                  jobs=
    +./stack.sh:exit_trap:493                  [[ -n '' ]]
    +./stack.sh:exit_trap:499                  '[' -f /tmp/tmp.g8xjCU2yg2 ']'
    +./stack.sh:exit_trap:500                  rm /tmp/tmp.g8xjCU2yg2
    +./stack.sh:exit_trap:504                  kill_spinner
    +./stack.sh:kill_spinner:399               '[' '!' -z '' ']'
    +./stack.sh:exit_trap:506                  [[ 1 -ne 0 ]]
    +./stack.sh:exit_trap:507                  echo 'Error on exit'
    Error on exit
    +./stack.sh:exit_trap:509                  type -p generate-subunit
    +./stack.sh:exit_trap:510                  generate-subunit 1593717952 1120 fail
    +./stack.sh:exit_trap:512                  [[ -z /opt/stack/logs ]]
    +./stack.sh:exit_trap:515                  /usr/bin/python3.6 /opt/stack/devstack/tools/worlddump.py -d /opt/stack/logs
    nova-compute: no process found
    neutron-dhcp-agent: no process found
    neutron-l3-agent: no process found
    neutron-metadata-agent: no process found
    neutron-openvswitch-agent: no process found
    +./stack.sh:exit_trap:524                  exit 1
    stack@opstack:~/devstack$
```

```
cd /etc/systemd/system/
vi systemctl start devstack@sl-api.service
ExecStart = /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --procname-prefix senlin-api --ini /etc/senlin/senlin-api-uwsgi.ini

file not exist
/usr/local/bin/uwsgi
```

Comment: cd /etc/systemd/system

Comment: Apparently this is an attempt at a self-answered question.  If you want this to be helpful to other people, question and the answer need to explain (in clear English) what your problem is / was, and what the solution does.  This Q&A is currently unintelligible, and it is unlikely to help anyone.

Answer (score -1):

cd /usr/bin
ls | grep uwsgi
if file is here then use if you don't have it here then you can reinstall using apt-get install uwsgi or pip install uwsgi
cd /usr/local/bin
ln -s /usr/bin/uwsgi uwsgi

./unstack.sh
./stach.sh
here we go.....